# Understanding list of t in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I need a solution that will;
Behave like Order and order detail but in a list(of t) 'I think that the list(of T) class should work well but I cannot figure out how to store and call the data.

Is there a way to link one string in a list and when I call that one string in a list have the second list show the subItems?

I have been looking for a way to link two lists together and haven't found a way to accomplish this.

Is there anyone who might know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use something like a `Dictionary(Of String, List(Of T))`.  This would let you associate multiple `List(Of T)` instances to string values.

Comment: I can agree with that.  I don't know how to accomplish it though.  I have researched so much about this and it is not clear to me.
Thanks for your suggestion